# How to install provider during installation (custom action of MSI installer)

Tags: windows-installer

I need to installer parts of Microsoft Office to my Desktop application. I have created custom action for this purpose.

[image: Custom action]

Installer started, but than ... ups, it said me that another installation is running. Of course another installation is running, because this is action only of main installation.

[image: Another installation is running]

Hmmm, what I can doing to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two msi can't run at the same time. Instead of custom action, try to install Office parts as prerequisites. Prerequisites can be used in bootstrapper.

Comment: This is maybe a solution, because you are right about two MSI-packages, but I need very special component "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable" with X64 edition. This component is absent in standard list of packages, and any attempt adding this component with project property -> prerequesite is ignored by MSI engine, my MSI install without any bootstraper. Maybe standard MS project template is wrong ? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2022InstallerProjects

Comment: If you're still want to install using custom action, try to schedule it before InstallInitialize action and make it synchronous.

Comment: Thank you, @Vivek Jaiswal. Cool Idea. I want to avoid readme.txt and description of my software at all, because this software is small addition for huge industrial robot and customers of this robot ready only to one click for installation, no more. This is condition from robot manufacturer. But I don't know how to use scheduler (and what exactly scheduler?) during installation. Can you get me any example?

Comment: In MSI technology, whenever you create a custom action, you need to provide some  mandatory settings like when do you want to execute it during installation.  This is what I meant by scheduling.